# Discord bot extension runs fine but doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I was able to load the extension just fine, but whenever I try it out on Discord as Qball/.Qball/_Qball, the bot won't answer.

**Quokkabot.py (main)**

```
import discord
import random
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension('.cogs.Quokkabot2')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} JOINED THE PARTY!'.format(client))


client.run('token')
```

**Quokkabot2.py (cog)**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

@commands.command(aliases=['Qball, test'])
async def _Qball(ctx):
    responses = [#answers]
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')

def setup(client):
    client.add_command(Qball(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Commands on a cog should be defined as instance methods on that cog.

```
class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['Qball, test'])
    async def _Qball(self, ctx):
        responses = [#answers]
        await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')
```

Then, in your main

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
client.add_cog(Commands(client))
```

Comment: Hello @Silvio Mayolo, thank you very much for your answer. I did as you told and now I get this error: `client.add_cog(Commands(client))
NameError: name 'Commands' is not defined`

Comment: `Commands` is what you named your class in the code snippet. Did you mistype the class name perhaps?

Comment: I added `def main():` before the command and I don't get the error anymore, but the bot still doesn't answer in Discord.